# Generic detail view Index must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to have one form and one modelin one view which is working. But when I am trying to save the form I am getting the error message: **Generic detail view Index must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.**

Here are my views nad urls:

```
class Index(generic.CreateView):
    template_name='home.html'
    form_class=DistributionForm
    models=Lecturer
    queryset = Lecturer.objects.all()


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['lecturer_list'] = Lecturer.objects.order_by('lecturer')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


app_name='distribution'

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.Index.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('hocalar/<slug:slug>/',views.LecturerDistribution.as_view(),name='lecturer_distribution'),
    path('dersler/<slug:slug>/',views.LectureDistribution.as_view(),name='lecture_distribution'),
]



urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**EDIT**
Here are my other two views

```
class LecturerDistribution(generic.DetailView):
    model=Lecturer
    template_name='lecturer.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lecturer_distribution', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['distribution'] = Distribution.objects.filter(lecturer=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context



class LectureDistribution(generic.DetailView):
    model=Lecture
    template_name='lecture.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lecture_distribution', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['distribution_'] = Distribution.objects.filter(lecture=self.object).order_by('-created_on')
        return context
```

And here my Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<div class="container">
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="Ara">
        </div>
        <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
        <table class="table table-hover results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th >Hoca</th>
        <th >Ders</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning no-result">
        <td><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Sonuç Yok</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            {%for lec in lecturer_list%}
        <tr>
        <td>
                    <p ><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'distribution:lecturer_distribution' slug=lec.slug%}">{{lec.lecturer}}</a></p>
        </td>
        <td>
                    {%for ders in lec.lecture.all%}
                        <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'distribution:lecture_distribution' slug=ders.slug%}">{{ders.lecture}}</a>,
                    {% endfor%}
                </td>
        </tr>
            {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>



<div class="col-md-2 float-right ">
  <button style= "position: fixed; top:175px; " type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add New Distribution</button>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Distribution</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
             </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<style >
        body{
  padding:20px 20px;
}

.results tr[visible='false'],
.no-result{
  display:none;
}

.results tr[visible='true']{
  display:table-row;
}

.counter{
  padding:8px;
  color:#ccc;
}
    </style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });

  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','false');
  });

  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','true');
  });

  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;

  if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
    else {$('.no-result').hide();}
          });
});
</script>



{% endblock content%}
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: can you post the detailview and form html

Comment: sure I posted it

Answer (score 0):

I think i found your problem, because you are using the get_object() in your post function in your index view.

see code:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """
    Return the object the view is displaying.
    Require `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument in the URLconf.
    Subclasses can override this to return any object.
    """
    # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
    # like DateDetailView
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    # Next, try looking up by primary key.
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
    if pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
    # Next, try looking up by slug.
    if slug is not None and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
        slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
    # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
    if pk is None and slug is None:
        raise AttributeError(
            "Generic detail view %s must be called with either an object "
            "pk or a slug in the URLconf." % self.__class__.__name__
        )
    try:
        # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
        obj = queryset.get()
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
```

This is the code for get_object(), because you don't have a pk and no slug available. It returns the generic detail view error.

```
 raise AttributeError(
            "Generic detail view %s must be called with either an object "
            "pk or a slug in the URLconf." % self.__class__.__name__
        )
```

You can delete the def post in your index view because the form_valid() that your are using is already in the create view. You don't need it.

Comment: I don't understand why I need this, I don't want to redirect to a page with the pk. I want to redirect to the home page (Index View).

Comment: I updated my answer, can you see if this it your problem @EkremÜçüncü

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `success_url` to your CreateView to redirect you to the homepage

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class Index(generic.CreateView):
    template_name='home.html'
    form_class=DistributionForm
    models=Lecturer
    queryset = Lecturer.objects.all()
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Otherwise it will redirect you to the model's `get_absolute_url` path

Comment: what does your models `get_absolute_url` look like?

Comment: I have no get_absolute_url